# CSS - positioning of text sections inside individual line items <li> of ordered list <ol>

Tags: css, flexbox

In my particular example, I am trying to choose moves of a chess game. My output should be something like this:

1. e2 – e4 e7 – e5
2. ♘ g1 – f3 d7 – d6
3. ♗ f1 – c4 ♝ c8 – g4

etc..

There would be 4 items on each line: white piece (empty if it's a pawn), move for the white piece, black piece, move for the black piece

I want the 4 items to be vertically aligned with each other.

My CSS uses an ordered list (ol). To align the four items on each line, I've tried the following:

1) span:nth-child with a left position for items 1 through 4. This works fine.

```
ol.chessgame li span { position: absolute ; }
ol.chessgame li span:nth-child(1) {left: 60px;} ...
<ol class="chessgame">
<li><span></span><span>e2 – e4</span><span></span><span>e7 – e5</span></li>
```

2) display:flex with a width for each item. This displays correctly EXCEPT that the line numbers produced by (ol) don't appear.

```
ol.jeu { max-width: 300px ; }
.movement { display: flex ; }
.movement span:nth-child(1) { width: 10% ; } ...
<ol class="jeu">
<li class="movement"><span></span><span>e2 – e4</span><span></span><span>e7 – e5</span></li>
```

**My question: What am I doing wrong in case 2 with the display:flex?**

(Another question could be - is there a better way of doing this?)

Sample code. The first list shows the way I would like it to look. The second list is missing the list-item numbers.

http://jsbin.com/lomofivoka/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Add `&nbsp;` where you are not using icons and add `position: relative` and `display: block` to spans.

Here is the updated code :-

[Code - https://jsbin.com/meculimowo/1/edit?html,output](https://jsbin.com/meculimowo/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: This is the closest to what I was trying to do, thank you. Sometimes CSS seems to me like it's not based on logic, it's more just throwing a bunch of code at a slippery wall to see what sticks. I'm still not sure why putting a flexbox inside li tabs will cause the ol line counters to just disappear.

Comment: typically flexbox only works on block elements....and since span is not a block element, flexbox wont work properly on spans, if you try it with div it might have worked, but again you are right css is very simple sometimes and sometimes its a headache.... if you want to debug your css put `border : 1px solid red;` to elements and check how they behave.....

Answer (score 0):

As a UI/UX engineer myself, I cringe at the actual need of a table, but truth is, whenever you are in need of tabular form, a table does make sense. It makes it easier and the only downside is responsiveness but considering that this is rather a small table, you will be fine.

I would suggest not over thinking this and go for "easy does it". However, I am providing you with an `ol` option in my demo as well. You can choose which one works better for you.

But here is the Table one:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>e2 – e4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>e7 – e5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>♘</td>
        <td>g1 – f3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>d7 – d6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>♗</td>
        <td>f1 – c4</td>
        <td>♝</td>
        <td>c8 – g4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>♗</td>
        <td>f1 – c4</td>
        <td>♝</td>
        <td>c8 – g4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table td:nth-child(odd){
    width:20%;
}
table td:first-child{
    width:5%;
}
table td:nth-child(even){
    width:10%;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Check out the [**demo**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/zqBdQp)

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure a table would be easier, but all the articles I see say "don't use a table for HTML layout!" But I learned something from reading your code.

Comment: Those articles are correct. Don't use tables for HTML layout, They don't say Don't use tables for tabular forms. What they mean is don't use tables to format the architecture of your website. For instance. Back in the day, pages were built using nested tables. One huge table that nested 5 smaller tables within it (One for the header, another for the content, footer, and 2 sidebars). That is a no-no. But if you need a table, then you need a table my friend :)

Comment: My only issue with tables is the lack of responsiveness but in your case, since they are only 5 columns wide, the tables holding your chess thing will shrink to 320px without producing a horizontal scrollbar. So you are safe in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure of what order they are supposed to be, so let me know and I can adjust accordingly. The main point of this demo is to show how [**`flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [**`counter`**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp) can make organizing a multi column layout stable and manageable.

The following is the list of changes:

- Each `span` is converted to a `div`
- The first `div` of each *"cell"* is merged into the second `div`
- Each *"column"* is wrapped in a `section`
- Each pair of `sections` are wrapped in a `div`
- Make the `body` a `flex-column`†
- Make the `div#chessgame` and `div#jeu` `flex-rows`‡
- Make each `section` a `flex-column`
- Assign a CSS `counter` to each `div`

† consists of:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
```

‡ consists of:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
```

[**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/qeyuku/2/edit?html,css,output)

**Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    body {
      counter-reset: cnt;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      position: relative;
    }
    .chessgame,
    .jeu {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
    }
    section {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      margin: 20px;
      width: 8em;
    }
    section div {
      counter-increment: cnt;
      height: 30px;
    }
    section div:before {
      content: counter(cnt)". ";
    }
    .space {
      margin-left: 1ex;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="chessgame">
    <section>
      <div>e2 – e4</div>
      <div>♘ g1 – f3</div>
      <div>♗ f1 – c4</div>
      <div>♘ b1 – c3</div>
      <div>♘ f3 x e5</div>
      <div>♗ c4 x f7</div>
      <div>♘ c3 – d5#</div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="space">e7 – e5</div>
      <div class="space">d7 – d6</div>
      <div>♝ c8 – g4</div>
      <div>g7 – g6</div>
      <div>♝ g4 x d1</div>
      <div>♚ e8 – e7</div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="jeu">
    <section>
      <div class="movement">e2 – e4</div>
      <div class="movement">♘ g1 – f3</div>
      <div class="movement">♗ f1 – c4</div>
      <div class="movement">♘ b1 – c3</div>
      <div class="movement">♘ f3 x e5</div>
      <div class="movement">♗ c4 x f7</div>
      <div class="movement">♘ c3 – d5#</div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div>e7 – e5</div>
      <div>d7 – d6</div>
      <div>♝ c8 – g4</div>
      <div>g7 – g6</div>
      <div>♝ g4 x d1</div>
      <div>♚ e8 – e7</div>
    </section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the time and trouble, I will play around with this to learn more about counters.

Comment: No problem @JacquesKilchoer , is this the way you wanted the pieces or is it another way?